# Add border to an inline input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, forms

I have three inputs in one line, and I want to add only to the 3rd input a border, like a box. I add a class for the 3rd input to adjust the border with no success.

```css
.valid-version {
  border: #0f7864;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1 control-label">product</label>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product">
  </div>
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 control-label">version</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="version">
  </div>

  <div class="valid-version">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 two-lines control-label">Valid</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Go to full view (in order to have all the inputs in one line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the wide screen Bootstrap column becomes floating. Because of this the parent block decides that it is empty. And its height becomes zero.

So you need to add the `overflow: hidden;` property to the `.valid-version` class. This property causes the parent block to take the dimensions considering its floating children.

```css
.valid-version {
  border: #0f7864;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1 control-label">product</label>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product">
  </div>
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 control-label">version</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="version">
  </div>

  <div class="valid-version">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 two-lines control-label">Valid</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `select` in your class because you added css in main div of select

```css
.valid-version select{
  border: #0f7864;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-1 control-label">product</label>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product">
  </div>
  <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 control-label">version</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="version">
  </div>

  <div class="valid-version">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 two-lines control-label">Valid</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>yes</option>
        <option>no</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want also the title `valid` inside the same border.